# Создание объектов в golang

Tags: алгоритм, golang, память

Привет.

Никак не могу понять, в чём отличия между следующими строками:

```
memoryIndex := map[string][]PMemoryIndex.SCoordBlockIndex{}
```

и

```
memoryIndex := make(map[string][]PMemoryIndex.SCoordBlockIndex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, ни в чём. Просто в первом случае вы можете сразу указать несколько значений:

```
m := map[string]strint{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

А во втором вы можете выделить памяти (так же как и со слайсом, добавление элементов в такую хэш-таблицу будет чуть быстрее):

```
m := make(map[string]string, 100)
```